# dotnet run в Rider

Tags: c#, .net, rider

решил перейти с VS code на Rider, но не могу понять как использовать терминал в нем.
В VS code при написании кода его сразу можно тестировать в терминале командой dotnet run.
При любых правках кода в терминале он запускается обновленный  и без проблем,
но вот в Rider у меня не получается работать с этой командой.
Вот что происходит при вводе dotnet run в созданном в Rider проекте:

[image: dotnet run в созданном в Rider проекте]

А вот что происходит когда я запускаю код созданный в VS code:

[image: А вот что происходит когда я запускаю код созданный в VS code]

Команда dotnet run работает,
но после правок кода она продолжает выводить старый код, не меняя его на новый.
Так как мне нормально создать проект в Rider, что-бы он нормально запускался через терминал?

Comment: Visual Studio же вроде работает под Windows, зачем вот это вот всё? Вы пробовали перед dotnet run вызывать dotnet build? А потом, JB Rider - коммерчнское ПО, у них должна быть хорошая справка и техподдержка.

Comment: В Rider справа есть кнопки Run и Debug. Зачем запускать через терминал, если IDE умеет нормально запускать код?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно путь по которому вы исполняете команду не содержит .csproj

Есть возможность открыть в проводнике и проверить?
если так, то найдите ту директорию, которая содержит, перейдите в консоле в нее и уже тогда выполняйте dotnet run